# Set vue.config.js to build different pages depends on environments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Currently I'm using vue with webpack to build MPA and I the following

```
pages: {
  index: {
   entry: ...
   template: ...
   ...
  }
   page1: {
   entry: ...
   template: ...
   ...
  }

}
```

I want to add a debug page if the env is not production. What is the best/proper way to achieve this? I'm aware that it's possible to have multiple config files, but I hoping there's a better way than just copy the codes and make that small modification, and having all the future settings required to be in two places instead of one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the export is simply a flat object, define it ahead of time, and then evaluate the environment and assign more properties if truthful.

```
let pages = {....}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    pages[x] = y
}
```

Then use this value in the `module.exports` definition:

```
module.exports = {
   // ....
   pages
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I knew it'd something simple I missed.